# Dynatree - How To Transform The json Coming From Server?

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I'm looking for some help with [dynatree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/index.html) plugin.

I need to transform the json coming from the server to make it dynatree 
compatible (I'm not allowed to do it on the server side),

This below apparently doesn't work:

```
                    initAjax: { 
                            url: '/admin/tenant/jsontree', 
                            data: { 
                                    tenantId: 1 
                            }, 
                            success: function(data) { 
                                    // do modifications to the data returned from server 
                                   // and return formatted data 
                            } 
                    }
```

And I couldn't find a callback for it in the documentation. 
So my question is: is it possible to do that initial transformation with some 
callbacks or should I be looking for some other plugins?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at 'Loading custom formats' in the docs:

```
http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html
```

basically you can pass the standard $.ajax() options to initAjax(), such as `dataFilter`.
(There is also a - yet undocumented - `postProcess` callback option.)

Comment: hey thanks, I tried that and it worked, but after realized that jstree suits my needs better.